# Why is async.map passing only the value of my JSON?

Tags: json, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I have a function in node.js that looks like this:

```
exports.getAllFlights = function(getRequest) {

// this is the package from npm called "async"
async.map(clients, getFlight, function(err, results) {
    getRequest(results);
  });
}
```

The variable clients should be a JSON that looks like this: 
`{'"A4Q"': 'JZA8187', "'B7P"': 'DAL2098' }`.

I expect that the map function will pass the individual indices of the array of the variable clients to getFlight. However, instead it passed the values of that each(ex: 'DAL2098', 'JZA8187' and so on).

Is this the expected functionality? Is there a function in async that will do what I want?

The signature of `getFlight` is `getFlight(identifier, callback)`. Identifier is what is currently messed up. It returns `callback(null, rtn)`. Null reprsents the nonexistence of an error, rtn represents the JSON that my function produces.

Comment: so you just want the index of each object in the array to be mapped to the getFlight function?

Comment: Because clients is an object, not array.

Comment: I expected it to pass in {'"A4Q"': 'JZA8187'} and {"'B7P"': 'DAL2098' } individually to getFlight.

Comment: and get the keyA4Q or B7P?

Comment: Yes, I wanted it to pass in `{'"A4Q"': 'JZA8187'}` so I could use Object.keys() and Object.values()

Comment: @BenCooper  Yes, you need to show the parameters of the `getFlight()` function.

Comment: Edited question appropriately

Comment: Well what you could do, is create a event, attach the event for complete request from the restful service. Then listen for that event, pass the returned data to the event and then processed it with.for(var key in clients) {
var value = clients[key];
 getFlight(key,value);
}

Comment: this way, there will be no race condition,because the only way that for loop can start is when the event is fired,which indicates a result was returned from the server. Does this still not make sense?

Comment: or if you dont prefer custom events, use a promise as wrapper then call then when the result is returned.preferably bluebird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the expected result. The documentation is not very clear but all iterating functions of async.js pass the values of the iterable, not the keys. There is the `eachOf` series of functions that pass both key and value. For example:

```
async.eachOf(clients, function (value, key, callback) {
    // process each client here
});
```

Unfortunately there is no `mapOf`.

If you don't mind not doing things in parallel you can use `eachOfSeries`:

```
var results = [];
async.eachOfSeries(clients, function (value, key, callback) {
   // do what getFlight needs to do and append to results array
}, function(err) {
  getRequest(results);
});
```

Another (IMHO better) workaround is to use proper arrays:

```
var clients = [{'A4Q': 'JZA8187'},{'B7P': 'DAL2098'}];
```

Then use your original logic. However, I'd prefer to use a structure like the following:

```
var clients = [
    {key: 'A4Q', val: 'JZA8187'},
    {key: 'B7P', val: 'DAL2098'}
];
```

Comment: Nice touch explaining what async.js does

Answer (score 0):

First create a custom event. Attach a listener for return data. then process it.

```
var EventEmitter = require('events');
var myEmitter = new EventEmitter();



  myEmitter.emit('clients_data',{'"A4Q"': 'JZA8187'}); //emit your event where ever

  myEmitter.on('clients_data', (obj) => {
    if (typeof obj !=='undefined') {
        if (obj.contructor === Object && Object.keys(obj).lenth == 0) {
            console.log('empty');
        } else {
            for(var key in obj) {
            var value = obj[key];
            //do what you want here 
            }

        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to format your clients object properly before you can use it with `async.map()`. [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) `_.map()` can help you:

```
var client_list = _.map(clients, function(value, key) {
    var item  = {};
    item[key] = value;

    return item;
});
```

After that, you will have an array like:

`[ { A4Q: 'JZA8187' }, { B7P: 'DAL2098' } ]`

Then, you can use `async.map()`:

```
exports.getAllFlights = function(getRequest) {

  async.map(client_list, getFlight, function(err, results) {
    getRequest(results);
  });
};
```